# Algorithm to find future highs in an array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming

I am solving one of the problems in hackerrank, for that, I need to solve a subproblem. Given an array, I need to fill another array to fill all the future highs. To explain with an example

```
arr1 = [5,2,4,1,4,7,2,4,3]
output: [true, true, true, true, true, false, true, false, false]
```

At index 0, 5 has a future high 7. Same way 2 has a future high 4, 4 has a future high 7, etc., I was able to calculate the future peak using flood filling technique, meaning as the first element 5 has a future peak at 7, all the items in between can be filled with `true`.

However, that is still not O(N) because consider this array

```
arr2 = [8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
output: [false, false .... false]
```

My flood fill technique would consume O(N²) in this scenario as there is nothing to flood fill here. Flood fill is still better than brute force, but I need the most optimal Algo here.

I am curious to know if O(N) is possible for this for all cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in O(n).

```
#include <iostream>    
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n = 9;
    int arr[] = {5,2,4,1,4,7,2,4,3};
    int fut[] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    
    int maxAfter = arr[n - 1];
    
    for(int i = n - 2; i >= 0; i--){
        if(arr[i] < maxAfter) fut[i] = 1;
        else maxAfter = arr[i];
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) cout<<fut[i]<<" ";
}
```

Starting from the end of the array, travel back to the start, always storing the biggest value found, this value will be used to say if there is someone bigger than the value in the index you are looking at the moment.